# Simple matrix (vector) identity proof

Tags: matrices

During my experiments with matrices I found the following simple identity

$$a^{T}Cabb^{T}=ba^{T}Cab^{T}$$

where $a(m,1),b(m,1)$ are the column vectors, and $C(m,m)$ is a regular matrix. How to prove it? Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple: $a^T C a\in\mathbb R$ is scalar. Therefore you can move it anywhere you can move a scalar:

$$ (a^TCa) bb^T = b (a^T C a) b^T. $$